# Passing an int variable into a new view controller (in code) - Objective C - Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c

So I have two view controllers, and I am trying to pass an int variable named `currentScore` to the new view controller, when moving from the first view controller `JPViewController` to the `LeaderboardViewController`

With this code below, I can successfully move between view controllers, but I cannot seem to pass the data properly.

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        LeaderboardViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"lbvc"];
        LeaderboardViewController.scoreToBeAdded = currentScore;
        [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The 3rd line above: `LeaderboardViewController.scoreToBeAdded = currentScore;` gives me the error `Property 'scoreToBeAdded' not found on object of type 'LeaderboardViewController'`.

However,In my LeaderboardViewController.h file I have made a reference to the *scoreToBeAdded, so I'm not sure why it can't find the property there.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface LeaderboardViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

@property int *scoreToBeAdded;

@end
```

I guess that is my first problem I need to solve, but just to clarify what I'm doing, I've also included what I'm planning to do with the variable in the implementation file below too.

Thanks very much in advance!

```
// LeaderboardViewController.m

- (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        NSLog(@"Leaderboard view loaded w new score to add: %i", _scoreToBeAdded);
    }
```

Comment: You can take global int variable in second view controller and set it just before present that view controller and access it on viewDidLoad of second view controller

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
LeaderboardViewController.scoreToBeAdded = currentScore;
```

should be

```
viewController.scoreToBeAdded = currentScore;
```

And

```
@property int *scoreToBeAdded;
```

should be

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) int scoreToBeAdded;
```

Answer (score 1):

in your .h file declare

```
@property(nonatomic,assign)int scoreToBeAdded;
```

and synthesize it in your .m file.

Comment: Yep, that worked however I didn't need to synthesize it in my .m file for it to work, is that just best practice?